# python: multiply an input by a number in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I am trying to multiple a user given number, by another part of code inside a pre made dictionary. Here is my example code

```
randomdict = {'22' : {'name' : 'sponge', 'price' : 1}}
choice = input("Enter a number: ")
amount = input("How much of that item?: ")
if choice in randomdict:
    price  = amount * (randomdict['price'])
    print("Price is "+str(price))
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the amount the user inputted in, multiplied by the price of the item which is saved in the dict `randomdict`. How do I do this? I have tried time and time again but cannot figure it out

Comment: Choice and amount are strings. You need to parse them as numbers first.

Comment: if I were to do that, then would the line `price = amount * (randomdict['price'])` be correct?

Comment: Once everything in the equation is a number, yes, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`randomdict['price']` doesn't exist.  You want `randomdict[choice]['price']`

Further, you want your `amount` to be an integer if you want to calculate the price.

```
price  = int(amount) * randomdict[choice]['price']
```

As a side-note: `price` may not be the greatest name for this value. This value is really a `total` (price x quantity) not the `price`. Writing that  out explicitly:

```
quantity = int(amount)
price = randomdict[choice]['price']
total = price * quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

what for is the `'22'` in the 1st row? You have a dictionary inside a dictionary, the price is inside the inner dictionary. 
Your input must be `'22'` and so you would choice be `'22'` and the dict you have to look in is `randomdict[choice]`. To get the price you need `randomdict[choice]['price']`

```
if choice in randomdict:
    price  = amount * (randomdict[choice]['price'])
    print("Price is "+str(price))
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two step procedure.
    if choice in randomdict:
      z=randomdict[choice]
      p=z['price']
      price=int(amount)*p